# maven assembly , how to specify the class i want to packaged in my jar

Tags: java, apache, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I need to use the plugin maven assembly from wrap one class of my application in a jar.
when i use maven, the plugin assembly package all class in my package  in target jar.
how  to specify the class i want to packaged in my jar.

Comment: Please post your project directory layout and your POM file.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use the maven assembly plugin? If you want to generate a jar file you could use the [maven jar plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html) instead.

It would be something like that:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>com/company/project/package/SomeClass.class</include>
            <include>com/company/project/anotherpackage/AnotherClass.class</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

The plugin can be executed in a common `mvn package` execution.

Comment: thank you for answer.
the issue is same when i use the maven assembly. the archive Jar contains all class in my package.